# why i got error ora-00904 invalid identifier?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables MR_FILES and WEBSITE_USERS I need to insert data from first table to second table but I got the error ora-00904 WEBSITE_USERS.PATIENT_NO invalid identifier , but the column already exist in the tables with same datatype number(12), this is the SELECT statement :

```
INSERT INTO WEBSITE_USERS (NAME) 
SELECT (FIRST_NAME_A) 
FROM MR_FILES 
WHERE  WEBSITE_USERS.PATIENT_NO = MR_FILES.PATIENT_NO;
```

what is the error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like you want an `update`:

```
UPDATE WEBSITE_USERS
    SET NAME = (SELECT FIRST_NAME_A 
                FROM MR_FILES 
                WHERE WEBSITE_USERS.PATIENT_NO = MR_FILES.PATIENT_NO
               )
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM MR_FILES 
                  WHERE WEBSITE_USERS.PATIENT_NO = MR_FILES.PATIENT_NO
                 );
```

Comment: DO we need exists clause here, only the update when patient_no is available should work.

Comment: Where exits is redundant and get rid of (name) you are repeating op's mistake

Comment: @Abdullah . . . Such a comment is not helpful.

Comment: @GordonLinoff no its helpful i tried INSERT statement and you gave the correct idea which is UPDATE not INSERT if you need to be the correct answer i will do it for you just correct your answer :)

Comment: @Abdullah . . . Oh, I see.  The `(NAME)` was still there in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this update statement:

```
UPDATE WEBSITE_USERS SET NAME = (SELECT FIRST_NAME_A 
                                 FROM MR_FILES 
                                 WHERE WEBSITE_USERS.PATIENT_NO = MR_FILES.PATIENT_NO );
```